# robots.txt: block all webpages except a few number of webpages?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a few doubts regarding *robots.txt*. Say, my domain is `stackoverflow.com`,

A) Will the code below do the following for all the crawlers?

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /

Allow: /$
Allow: /a/$
Allow: /a/login.php
Allow: /a/login.php?return=/pligg/
```

1. Accepting `http://stackoverflow.com/` will accept `http://stackoverflow.com` too?
2. Accepting `http://stackoverflow.com/a/`
3. Accepting `http://stackoverflow.com/a/login.php`
4. Accepting `http://stackoverflow.com/a/login.php?return=/pligg/`
5. Not accepting any other page on `http://stackoverflow.com`

B) Which is right: *robots.txt* or *robot.txt*?

Answer (score 4):

A) Yes for the most important ones (Googlebot...).

1. Yes

B) The right file name is *robots.txt*.

Otherwise, the right code to do what you want is the following:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /

Allow: /a/$
Allow: /a/login.php
Allow: /a/login.php?return=/pligg/
```

Answer (score 3):

Your *robots.txt* is **invalid**. Line breaks are not allowed in a record. So it should look like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /$
Allow: /a/$
Allow: /a/login.php
Allow: /a/login.php?return=/pligg/
```

> Will the code below do the following for all the crawlers?

No, your *robots.txt* won’t work that way for all crawlers.

`Allow` is not part of the [original *robots.txt* specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html). Only some parsers will understand it (and they might have implemented the wildcards differently), all other parsers will ignore the `Allow` lines.

Comment: wiil google read *Allow* ?

Comment: @Nok Imchen: Yes, Google understands _Allow:_. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?hl=fr)

Comment: Do you have a reference line breaks not being allowed?  I was unaware of this myself.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: In the linked spec it says, "The file consists of one or more records separated by one or more blank lines (terminated by CR,CR/NL, or NL)". Later on "record" is defined, by listing lines that may/must exist in a record, which doesn’t contain blank ones (`User-agent`, `Disallow`, comments with `#`, unrecognised headers). So blank lines serve as record (aka. block) boundary exclusively.